# Is there a way in python to "emulate" running a python file?

Tags: python, subprocess, execution

I want to be able to programmatically run a file, arbitrarily give it inputs (stdin) at any time, and periodically poll for any stdout. I also want to be able to kill the process whenever I want.

Here's what I have tried:

```py
import subprocess
from threading import Thread


class Runner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            ["python", "x.py"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )

    def run(self):
        self.process.wait()

    def poll(self):
        print("got stdout:", self.process.stdout.readline().decode(), end="")

    def give_input(self, text=""):
        return self.process.stdin.write(bytes(text))

    def kill(self):
        self.process.kill()


r = Runner()
t = Thread(target=r.run)
t.start()
r.poll() # should be "hi"
r.poll() # should be "your name:"
r.give_input("hi\n")
r.kill()
t.join()
```

Here's the code in `x.py`

```py
print("hi")
input("Your name: ")
```

So in my demo, I start a thread that will call `run` which will run the process. Then, I `poll` for stdout twice. It should print

```
got stdout: hi
got stdout: Your name:
```

Afterwards, I give an stdin to the process -- `hi\n`.

At this point, the program should terminate, and I make sure of it by doing `r.kill()`.

However, the program does not work as expected.

Instead, the program freezes at the second `r.poll()`, and I'm not sure why. I suspect that since there is no newline, the program will keep reading, but I'm not sure how to prevent it from doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't show us the content of your `x.py` program. Beyond that note that I/O from/to a pipe is fully buffered -- not line buffered. Also, what is the point of `r.give_input("hi\n")` since you immediately attempt to kill the subprocess. Sending it the string "hi\n" is pointless. Also, your use of `threading.Thread` is pointless.

Comment: Also, your subject line is very confusing. You  ask "Is there a way in python to "emulate" running a python file?" What does it mean to "emulate" a Python program? Your question actually runs the Python program. It doesn't "emulate" it. So I have no idea what you mean by "emulate".

Comment: Ages ago, people would use [expect](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) to do this sort of thing, and apparently it still exists. There are also more pythonic solutions, like [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: @Kurtis Rader hello, I have sent the content of `x.py` (please read fully) and by emulate, it means like when you do `py x.py` on the terminal, you are able to interact with the file in real time. Why is using thread pointless? Why is sending it stdin pointless? From what I understand, is it not true that when you send it stdin it will wait for that to execute before killing the process?

Comment: @TurePålsson Thank you for your insight. I will take a look at pexpect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally came up with, (with code from [a non blocking read on `subprocess.PIPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/a-non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python):

```py
import subprocess
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread
from typing import IO
import io


class Runner:
    def __init__(self, stdin_input: str):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            "py x.py",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            bufsize=2,
            close_fds=False,
        )

        self.process.stdin.write(stdin_input.encode() + b"\n")

    def reader(self, out: IO[str], queue: Queue[bytes]):
        def enqueue_output(out: IO[str], queue: Queue[bytes]):
            stream = io.open(out.fileno(), "rb", closefd=False)
            while True:
                n = stream.read1()
                if len(n) > 0:
                    queue.put(n)
                else:
                    return

        t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(out, queue))
        # end thread when program ends
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def run(self, timeout=1):
        stdout_queue: Queue[bytes] = Queue()
        stderr_queue: Queue[bytes] = Queue()

        self.reader(self.process.stdout, stdout_queue)
        self.reader(self.process.stderr, stderr_queue)

        try:
            self.process.communicate(timeout=timeout)
        except:
            print("ERROR: TIMED OUT")
        finally:
            print("=== STDOUT ===")
            try:
                while True:
                    print(stdout_queue.get_nowait().decode(), end="")
            except Empty:
                print("=== STDOUT ===\n\n")

            print("=== STDERR ===")
            try:
                while True:
                    print(stderr_queue.get_nowait().decode(), end="")
            except Empty:
                print("=== STDERR ===")


r = Runner("5\n6")
r.run()
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out how to interactively give `stdin` to the process, nor was I able to periodically poll for `stdout`, but I was able to figure out a decent solution for my use case. Instead of getting output every so often, I instead just ran it for a few seconds before terminating the program.